# OpenAuth in ASP.NET MVC/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oauth, open-source

Enabling OpenAuth and allowing the user to login via Google, Yahoo, Facebook etc. is an common occurrence in websites. Is there an open-source library or project which can be consumed or referred to for implementing this functionality in ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nerd Dinner by Scott Hanselman, Phil Haack, Rob Conery et.al.](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com) is a good fit for your need.
It is a ASP.NET MVC project using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for the log-on entities DotNetOpenAuth supports.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DotNetOpenAuth. It supports Google, Yahoo,AOl, Wordpress etc..

This link has a sample project which gives you a good idea how to do this.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth

For Facebook, you may need to look into  facebook connect.

You can create a table in your database to store the Open Id (after hashing) . When user login with their other providers details (ex : google) you will get the open id. You can check that with what you have in your table and let the user to be a logged in user.